# Turn observable into array

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

When working with FireStore and Angular 5, my data is delivered as Observables. This means every time the data changes in the db, a new read is caused (and hence as I understand it, I am getting charged for that).

I do not want this "constant reload, constant charged" functionality. **I want one read, store my data in array, and close the connection.**

Here is my current code. How can I modify my service to store the products in an array upon retrieval from FireStore, so that all subsequent calls to my service return the data from that array (like a cache), without initiating another call to FireStore?

**product.service.ts**

```
products: Observable<Product[]>; // *** I want this to be an array of Product objects, not an observable

getProductsAll(): Observable<Product[]> {

    return this.afs.collection( 'products', ref => ref.orderBy( 'published', 'desc' ) ).snapshotChanges()
        .map( actions => {
            return actions.map( a =>  {
                const id = a.payload.doc.id; 
                const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Product;
                return { id, ...data };
            })
        })
```

**products.component.ts**

```
items: any;

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.productService.getProductsAll()
        .subscribe( products => { 
            this.items = products;
        })
}
```

For context, my little test app is causing too many reads and hitting FireStore's 50,000 reads/day quota with only 100 documents in the db.

Comment: [`toArray` operator](https://github.com/babygau/rxjs/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/toarray.md)?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is what I have come up with!** This *appears* to be doing what I want. It has the added advantage that after the first read of the data from FireStore, pages then load *significantly* faster using the "cached" data.

*However*, I would really appreciate **if someone could explain** if this is a good solution, or if there is a better one?

Essentially, I am converting the Observable into a Promise, use take(1), and use an if statement to avoid hitting the FireStore again.

**Service**

```
productsP: Promise<Product[]>;

getProductsAll(): Promise<Product[]> {

    // get from cache if possible
    if( !this.productsP ) {
        console.log("Getting all products from FireStore...");
        this.productsP = this.afs.collection( 'products', ref => ref.orderBy( 'published', 'desc' )).snapshotChanges()
        .map( actions => {
            return actions.map( a =>  {
                const id = a.payload.doc.id; 
                const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Product;
                return { id, ...data };
            })
        }).take(1).toPromise();
    }
    else {
        console.log("Getting all products from cache...");
    }

    return this.productsP;
}
```

**Component**: Change 'subscribe' to 'then'.

Comment: I would approach this the same way with the `take` operator. However I would use [shareReplay](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sharereplay.md) operator instead of toPromise to keep it as an observable.

Answer (score 0):

I have no tested this. But you could probably call `.take(1)` before subscribing.

**products.component.ts**

```
items: any;

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.productService.getProductsAll()
        .take(1).subscribe( products => { 
            this.items = products;
        })
}
```